# How can i add a searchable drop down list/filter of cities?

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu, django-templates, searchable

I created a map using Folium in Python to visualize some geospatial data. However, I want to add a search bar with a drop-down list of cities that I want to manually write. This search bar should allow users to search for a specific city and, upon selection, the map should automatically pan to that city's location. How can I achieve this functionality using Folium?

```
**index.html**

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>HomePage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--- NAVBAR -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Map App</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Map <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form}}
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <!---END NAVBAR-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-5">
            <div class="col-md-12 offset-md-0">
                {{m | safe }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>

**views.py**
from .forms import SearchForm
import win32api
from django.contrib import messages


# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')       
    else:
        form = SearchForm()
    address = Search.objects.all().last()
    location = geocoder.osm(address)
    lat = location.lat
    lng = location.lng
    country = location.country

    if lat == None or lng == None:
        address.delete()
        return HttpResponse('You address input is invalid')
    
    m = folium.Map(location=[12.7000, 122.9833], zoom_start=6,  min_zoom = 6)

    folium.Marker([lat, lng], tooltip ="Click for more", popup=country).add_to(m)
    
    m = m._repr_html_()
    context = { 
        'm': m,
        'form': form,
    }
     
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

**forms.py**

from django import forms
from .models import Search

class SearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Search
        fields = ['address', ]

**models.py**

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Search(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```